# Files and directories in Python on linux

Tags: python, linux, file, list, directory

I am looking for a code in python that allows me to take a directory and create a list similar to “ls –lR” containing all the files in the dir. and sub-dir. in a tabular form with their names, size, date last modified, permissions, users etc.

And also the total size of all the files in the directories and sub-directories.

I have used stats as of now, for the time, size and permissions and have appended the same in lists of which I have made tables. But to find the file name, the perm, owner and group. If I could get a neater code?

Comment: What are you doing right now exactly? `os.walk()` + `os.stat()`?

Comment: os.listdir(".") may help too.

Comment: i was looking for a recursive method, which allows me to store the file specifications in a tabular format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using python 2.x you can use :

```
commands.getoutput("ls –lR")
```

for python 3.0 you can try :

```
subprocess.check_output("ls -lR")
```

Hope it helps!

**EDIT**

Commands.getoutput and subprocess.check_output will return the output from the command you used as parameter.

Ex:

```
lslr = commands.getoutput("ls –lR") 
print lslr
```

This will give you exactly the same output as ls -lR in your current dir. Then it's up to you to filter whatever you need from there!

To change current dir use os.chdir(/desired/dir).

Comment: this i use in the terminal directly, but i want one in a .py file

Answer (score 6):

To traverse files recursively, you can use [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk). That will let you know all the file names that you need.

Once you have the file names, you can keep on using [`os.stat`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.stat) to get the user and group ids. Regarding permissions, I think there isn't any way to get them directly using the standard library, but you can use [`os.access`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.access) to test permissions one by one to find out which ones are set.

Comment: what i need is lets say, i am able to read all the files, then i should be able to store them a tabular format with different columns each specifying the files properties.

Comment: The thing is, i don't know to use recursion on this

Comment: To store in a tabular format, you can use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) from the standard library. Regarding recursion, you don't have to worry about that since `os.walk` will do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can traverse in the directory with os.stat as mention by jcollado and if you want to use the search pattern to search then use [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os


def iterbrowse(path):
    for home, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for filename in files:
            yield os.path.join(home, filename)


for full_name in iterbrowse("/root"):
    print full_name
```

Comment: Though this might answer the question, please also add a short explanation what your code does and why it solves the initial problem.